# Display message after session timeout

Tags: java, session

I am setting the session timeout in *web.xml* of application as

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout> 1 </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

So now after the session expires if user tries to do some operation I want to show a message saying “session expired relogin”. How to do so in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I found a number of solutions to this problem by entering the following in to Google:

"Java session expired message"

Here's one solution copied from the web:

> Create a SessionTimeout.java filter
>   and assign the filter a /app/*.jsp
>   pattern in the web.xml file.  This
>   will cause my filter to be called on
>   every request (ie When the user hits
>   the button after 30 minutes).  Exclude
>   the main page (login/login.jsp) from
>   this filter so a new session can be
>   established. The code for the filter
>   is very simple:

```
public class SessionTimeout implements Filter{
   RequestDispatcher rd = null;

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
   throws IOException, ServletException{
      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
      HttpSession session = req.getSession();

   // New Session so forward to login.jsp
   if (session.isNew()){
     requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login/login.jsp");
     requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
  }

  // Not a new session so continue to the requested resource
   else{
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}

public void init(filterConfig arg) throws ServletException{}
public void destroy(){}

}
```